# local alternative to files storages (S3, Azure Storage, etc.)

Tags: storage, file-storage

Are there any local alternatives to files storages (S3, Azure Storage, etc.)? I like the structure and architecture of S3 and would like to know if there is something similar to configure locally. I need to keep assets uploaded on my own server.